# Making multiple requests to api at once and display result to the template view engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, request

I just started learning with API. And I'm stumbling upon this problem.
MY GOAL: I would love to make two separate calls to marvel API at the same time. The first call will get all the data about the character and its id then I bundle them together inside a variable and save it in the database. Now, the second call will get all the comics data and these data will be embeded to the character object that was created during the first call. Now that I have this complete character variable. I can then send it to the view engine. But I do not know how to do it. Is there a simpler way to tackle this problem ?? Can you guys please let me know what I am doing wrong here...

```js
//Mongoose model set up for Thumbnail > path, and extension
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var thumbnailSchema = new Schema({
    path: "String",
    extension: "String"
});
var thumbnailPath = mongoose.model('thumbnailPath', thumbnailSchema);


//Mongoose model set up for Comics
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var comicsSchema = new Schema({
    title: "String",
    imagePath: [thumbnailSchema]
});
var Comics = mongoose.model('Comics', comicsSchema);

//Mongoose model set up for Character
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var characterSchema = new Schema({
    id: "Number",
    name: "String",
    description: "String",
    imagePath: [thumbnailSchema],
    comicsPath: [comicsSchema]
});
var Character = mongoose.model('Character', characterSchema);
```

```js
 //Create POST 
app.post('/', function(request,response){
var characterData = request.body.character;
var url = "https://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?name=" + characterData + "&ts=thor&apikey=PRIVATe"
    Request(url,function(error,res,body){
            var apiData = JSON.parse(body)
            if(!error && res.statusCode == 200){
            var newCharacter = Character ({
                id: apiData.data.results[0].id,
                name: apiData.data.results[0].name,
                description: apiData.data.results[0].description
            });
                newCharacter.imagePath.push({
                path: apiData.data.results[0].thumbnail.path,
                extension:                          apiData.data.results[0].thumbnail.extension
            });
        } else {
            var characterID = newCharacter.id
            var comicsURL = "https://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters/" + characterID + "/comics?limit=5&ts=thor&apikey=PRIVATE";
            Request(comicsURL,function(error,res,body){
                if(!error && res.statusCode == 200){
                    var comicsData = JSON.parse(body)
                    var newComics =  Comics({
                        title: comicsData.data.results[0].title,
                    });
                        newComics.imagePath.push({
                        path: comicsData.data.results[0].thumbnail.path,
                        extension:comicsData.data.results[0].extension
                    });
                        newCharacter.imagePath.push({newComics})
                        console.log(newComics);
                }
            })
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. In order for others to be able to help you, please provide some code.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone... I manage to take this one down by using a **request-promise** https://github.com/request/request-promise library. Now, with the searched character from the API as well as the comics front together. I can save it into a variable then take it to the database to store; that is happening in the background. With that finish, we can then hopefully pass it over successfully (will see) to the template engine to view. For future references......
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUoIg.png) [code2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQGOU.png)